# Check if a CSS class (added by clicking a button) exist and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect if a class exist and I'm trying to use this simple function to detect if an element has a class but it doesn't work.

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.menu'),
child = document.querySelector('.liked');

if (parent.contains(child)) {
$('.empty').addClass("none")
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".click", function() {
  $(".submenu").addClass("liked")
})

var parent = document.querySelector('.menu'),
  child = document.querySelector('.liked');

if (parent.contains(child)) {
  $('.empty').addClass("none")
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10vw/1.2em -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif
}

.none {
  display: none
}

.liked {
  color: red
}

button {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class=click>
ADD CLASS LIKED
</button>

<div class=menu><br>
  <span class=submenu>ONE</span>
  <span class=submenu>TWO</span>
  <span class=submenu>THREE</span>
</div>

<div class=empty><br>IF CLASS 'VISITED' EXIST, THIS TEXT MUST GO</div>
```

Comment: Something isn't clear on your question

Comment: Your `if` only runs one single time when the page loads. If you want it to be reevaluated on the click of the button, then move that code into your button click event. Or, if you want it to be evaluated *both* on page load AND button click, make it separate function, and call it when you load the page, as well as when you click the button.

Comment: I changed the question, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is only running once on page load. If you add it into a function like so, you can also run it in the click event.

```js
function childCheck() {
  var parent = document.querySelector('.menu'),
    child = document.querySelector('.liked');

  if (parent.contains(child)) {
    $('.empty').addClass("none")
  }
}

childCheck(); // run on page load (optional)

$(document).on("click", ".click", function() {
  $(".submenu").addClass("liked")
  childCheck(); // run here on click event
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 10vw/1.2em -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif
}

.none {
  display: none
}

.liked {
  color: red
}

button {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class=click>
ADD CLASS LIKED
</button>

<div class=menu><br>
  <span class=submenu>ONE</span>
  <span class=submenu>TWO</span>
  <span class=submenu>THREE</span>
</div>

<div class=empty><br>IF CLASS 'VISITED' EXIST, THIS TEXT MUST GO</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm not a fan of mixing jQuery with plain JS. Bouncing back and forth feels slightly sloppy, so as a bit of cleanup, my answer below will be solely jQuery.

Second, if you want to check again on the click of the button, then your code has to be in the `click` handler. Currently, you're only evaluating on the page load.

```
$(function() {

    checkIfParentContainsChild();   //Run on page load

    $(document).on("click", ".click", function() {
        $(".submenu").addClass("liked");
        checkIfParentContainsChild();   //Run on button click
    });

});

function checkIfParentContainsChild() {
    var $child = $(".menu .liked");        //Select all .liked with parent .menu
    var childExists = ($child.length > 0); //Result will be true or false

    //EDITED PER COMMENT
    if (childExists) {
        $('.empty').addClass("none");
    } else {
        // ...DOESN'T EXIST
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Santi.
How can I check if not exist then?

    else$('.empty').addClass("block"); //returns true if it doesn' exist

Comment: Thanks so much @Santi!